# Spring: Manually rollback a JPA transaction

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, transactional

The problem:

- I want to clash an in-memory data set with one stored in a SQL table.
- The match is conducted on multiple columns.
- The in-memory set could be quite large ~10000 records.
- I don't want to persist the in-memory set.
- I'm using Spring and JPA
- Multiple requests may be made concurrently

My attempted solution

- Start transaction
- Write the requested records to a "temporary" table
- Select the desired results by joining the two tables
- Rollback the transaction

(or in SQL terms)

```
CREATE TABLE player_details (
  firstname VARCHAR2(10),
  surname VARCHAR2(10),
  position VARCHAR2(2)
);

CREATE TABLE player_request (
  firstname VARCHAR2(10),
  surname VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO player_details (firstname, surname, position) VALUES ('Scottie', 'Pippen', 'SF');
INSERT INTO player_details (firstname, surname, position) VALUES ('Michael', 'Jordan', 'SG');
INSERT INTO player_details (firstname, surname, position) VALUES ('Dennis', 'Rodman', 'PF');

START TRANSACTION;

  INSERT INTO player_request (firstname, surname) VALUES ('Scottie', 'Pippen');
  INSERT INTO player_request (firstname, surname) VALUES ('Michael', 'Jordan');

  SELECT
    d.*
  FROM player_details d
  JOIN player_request r
    ON  d.firstname = r.firstname
    AND d.surname = r.surname;

ROLLBACK;

SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS player_requests
FROM family;
```

Gives:

```
FIRSTNAME  SURNAME    POSITION
---------- ---------- --------
Scottie    Pippen     SF       
Michael    Jordan     SG       

PLAYER_REQUESTS
---------------
              0
```

However, I can't find a way to get Spring to rollback the transaction.  I've tried several different annotations and approaches, but haven't found one that works.  Is there one?

(worst case scenario, I'll just give it a request id, commit then delete)

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your output?

Comment: Could you post some snippets of your code? Right now I believe `entityManager.getTransaction().setRollbackOnly()` might be what you need, given `entityManager` is injected by Spring

Comment: It is, but I don't think Spring appreciates you messing with it.  If I include that code get the error:  `Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`

Comment: I used a similar approach:  `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();` but it doesn't appear to save the data at all (even within the transaction).

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

This wasn't working:

```
@Transactional
public MatchResponse myMatcherMethod(MatchCriteria criteria) {
    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
    transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
    saveMatchCriteria(criteria);

    MatchResponse matches = getMatches();
    return matches;
}
```

It was giving me no matches.  Tomas asked my to post my code (thanks! +1) so I decided that I'd add a couple of extra lines to show that the criteria weren't being saved:

```
@Transactional
public MatchResponse myMatcherMethod(MatchCriteria criteria) {
    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
    transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
    saveMatchCriteria(criteria);

    //Added these lines:
    MatchCriteria savedCriteria = getMatchCriteria();
    System.out.println("# of criteria: " + savedCriteria.getIdentifiers().size());

    MatchResponse matches = getMatches();
    return matches;
}
```

..but at that point it started working!

So I guessed that my test query was causing a flush.  So I tried:

```
@Transactional
public MatchResponse myMatcherMethod(MatchCriteria criteria) {
    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
    transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
    saveMatchCriteria(criteria);

    // Replaced with:
    transactionStatus.flush();

    MatchResponse matches = getMatches();
    return matches;
}
```

..and it worked.

It seems obvious in hindsight:

- Repository.save -> JVM memory
- flush() -> Runs insert statement
- End transaction -> Commit

Looks like I need to brush up on my JPA life-cycle!